# How to reference cell on another sheet from cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet something like the following:

```
  A  B     C
1 1  cat   4
2 2  dog   4
3 3  bird  2
```

On another sheet, I want to get the data for a row based on value in a cell, e.g. if A1 = 2 I want to display the name of the animal for row 2 on a particular cell (in this case, `dog`)

I'm trying to use `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!'"&A1"')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, thanks @pnuts, I added the 4th param too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:C3,2)
```

Comment: How would that work if for example i want to display also the number of legs for each animal (the value in column C on sheet 1)

Comment: Thanks Gary, cool idea, but I can't get it to work. I get error "The value you entered is not from required list"

Comment: Are you using **EXCEL??**

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are using Excel on a Mac and are trying to match a number formatted as a number against a number formatted as text. Try copying A1 from one sheet to the other, then:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:C3,2,FALSE)
```

for animal name and change `2` to `3` for number of legs.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I still feel dumb as I don't know what you'd google to discover he was using a mac.  Something from the question itself or from his bio?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor  The clue is in the error message!!  It is not from the Windows version.